# Is it possible to use CSS Grid in place of Material UI's grid component?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, css-grid

The [Material-UI Grid Component](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) is based on flexbox and works very well. However, I'm trying to understand if there's any benefit to using it vs. CSS Grid, which is also very easy to use. I actually prefer CSS Grid, but I don't want to break the rest of the system by using it. Does it interfere with the rest of Material UI in any way?

Any insights? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use Material-UI grid and haven't used it in a very long time. The MUI grid seems like garbage and if you don't want to end up with weird bugs you have to do all sorts of workarounds with it. I found it easier to just use CSS Grid and/or Flexbox than trying to deal with the MUI grid quirks.

Comment: @Chris I don't know why this Q is closed, smh. Anyway, as the Q asks, does using css grid with material-ui cause any issues? Cos I was also trying to do the same and the layout just breaks. Whereas, the same code for the layout works great in my old project. I have a custom nav and footer with lots of custom functionalities (esp nav bar) and would like to keep it. But since it was breaking, I taught mui and css grid don't work hand in hand. So, am trying to redo the same code with mui grid which as you said is garbage. And to acheive simple stuff, I have to look for work arounds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main benefit the Grid component provides (compared to using flexbox directly) is the convenience of the theme-based breakpoint props (xs, sm, md, etc.) for easily adjusting the number of grid columns for different screen widths. If you prefer CSS Grid (and you aren't trying to support IE 11) or using flexbox directly, there's no reason not to use it. Nothing in Material-UI cares about whether or not you are using the Grid component.

In my own application, there are many cases where Material-UI's `Grid` component easily provides the desired layout and we go ahead and use it, and there are other cases where `Grid` would just get in the way and we use flexbox CSS directly (at the moment, our app still supports IE 11 so we aren't ever using CSS Grid, though I look forward to the point in the future when we change our supported browsers so that we can use CSS Grid).

Comment: I'd love to see an example of a where MUI Grid would just get in the way and it's easier to use flexbox instead.